# Run command from vim without leaving the vim window

Tags: vim

I'd like to run a command from `vim` editor as follows.

`:!mplayer %.mp3`

The mp3 file contains spoken word related to the opened file.

When I run the command, it will close the vim window.

I'd like the vim window stay open and hear the mp3 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
:execute 'silent !mplayer %.mp3 &' | redraw!
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163201/in-vim-how-do-you-run-a-command-silently-in-the-background)

Comment: This will first mix the text with mplayer output. When I press enter, I see only mplayer output

Comment: How about `:execute 'silent !mplayer %.mp3 &> /dev/null &' | redraw!`?

Comment: This works. It would be great, if I would have some possibity to interact with mplayer (e.g. pause, stop, back, forth).

Comment: You can always send signals via `:execute 'silent !killall -STOP mplayer' | redraw!` and `:execute 'silent !killall -CONT mplayer' | redraw!`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I'm trying to use -LEFT (on the place of -STOP or -CONT), but -LEFT seems to be not the right word.

Comment: Signals are a general UNIX mechanism of inter-process communication (see `man 7 signal`), you won't be able to use them to interact with `mplayer` beyond pausing it, continuing it and killing it. You could achieve more via dbus (see https://gnome-mplayer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DOCS/tech/dbus.txt).

Answer (score 2):

When you don't need to read the output of the external command, better use `system()` over `:!`, like this:

```
:call system('mplayer ' . expand('%') . '.mp3 &')
```

`%` won't be automatically expanded here, but that's no problem. The `&` is needed to avoid blocking Vim during playback. The call returns the output of `mplayer`, but you're apparently only interested in *hearing* the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to run the command on the background? Then add `&`:

```
:!mplayer %.mp3&
```

Comment: No, this will close the vim window as well

Comment: Do you mean it exits vim? Are you using vim in a terminal?